# Linux: how to list and optimize all JPEG files that were created today?

Tags: linux, bash

I am using that ssh script optimize.sh

```
cd /var/www/uploads/;
for i in *.jpg; do jpegoptim "$i" -m75; done
```

Is there a way to apply that only for NEW files (those created today) ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /var/www/uploads -name '*.jpg' -daystart -ctime 0 -exec jpegoptim "{}" -m75 \;
```